# spring boot: No validator could be found for constraint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have the two below fields, i add for each a validation, one a pattern and the other a custom validation, but in the two case i have an error

```
@ScheduleConstraint
private Map<ScheduleEnum, Short> workingHours;
```

> "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint
> 'ScheduleConstraint' validating
> type 'java.util.Map<cheduleEnum,
> java.lang.Short>'. Check configuration for 'workingHours'",

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$",message="Number of days must be positive")
private Short numDaysWeeklyOpening;
```

> "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint
> 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type
> 'java.lang.Short'. Check configuration for 'numDaysWeeklyOpening'"

Comment: Do you have the dependency  spring-boot-starter-validation added to your build file.?

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya yes